# Phone won't connect to mobile network

Tags: sim-card, network-signal, mobile-network

As of yesterday my phone was okay as I know I had a missed call and checked it on voicemail, but today I noticed that it is showing no signal when there should be one.

The last thing I know I did was to try *#61# to check the voicemail numbers as I was thinking of setting a longer timeout, but I didn't actually change it.

If I go into Additional call settings I get 'Network or SIM card error', but I expect that is linked to the lack of network. However, I wonder if something on the SIM is messed up.

I've turned it off/on a couple of times. Also tried a different SIM from a different service and that worked. It there anything I can try resetting?

It's an htc Tattoo on Android 1.6.

Comment: How long have you turned your phone off for? From my days on Blackberry support I do remember that while turning off for 30 seconds resets the connections on the phone itself. But if you leave it switched off for about 30 minutes then all the connections on the phone companies end are reset, and this can sort out some odd connection problems.

Comment: My phone has been off the original (Virgin UK) network for several days whilst I used a different SIM. Putting the old one back did not resolve the issue. I've mailed Virgin, but have yet to have a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bring the phone to your carrier's local store.  If a different SIM card from the same carrier works, then it's possible that your SIM card is damaged or corrupted.  The carrier may need to replace it for you.  Keep in mind that some carriers (or authorized reseller outlets) will charge you for this.

Comment: Don't know of a local store or of someone else using that carrier. The phone has been working fine with a different SIM, apart from another issue I raised. I'm considering changing carrier anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Check your APNs.  This might help: http://www.htc.com/mea-en/SupportViewNews.aspx?dl_id=949&news_id=654

Note: APNs are **provider specific**, the linked walkthrough covers KSA Mobily Postpaid Subscribers, but if you Google search: *(Your Provider) APN Settings*, it will turn up what you need and then just substitute THOSE values for the ones in the walkthrough.

Good luck!